# Android Google Play validate app without putting it in play store

Tags: android, google-play

We have developed small App for one company and we want it to be used in this company only. We're self hosting APK file and there is one problem. When people downloads our app Android is showing warning about "installing from untrusted source" - and that confuse a lot of workers.

Is there any way to validate or sign our APK with Google key but **without** putting it in PlayStore?

In addition I want to say, we have account on Google Play Console (we paid registration fee) but we dont want to use Google Enterprise solutions, which allows to create private app channels.

Comment: Are you sure that the "installing from unstrusted source" is looking at a signature on the apk and not on the fact that it is not installed via the play store?

Comment: "installing from untrusted source" is global not specific to certain app. Chrome, for example, warns you when you try to download an apk file outside the Play Store. Anyway, your question is clearly off topic for this site. You can try asking on Stack Exchange.